# How can i retrieve all nested array of object element which has been matched by using "elementMatch" mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have array of object and every object contain array of object "Conversation".We need to get the count/elements where the field **deliveryStatus** is **sent** and **userId** is exits

```
[{
_id: "12312312"
conversation:[
        {
            "messageInformation" : {
                "deliveryStatus" : "sent"

            },
            "userId" : 12
        },
        {
            "messageInformation" : {
                "deliveryStatus" : "sent",
            }

        }
  ]},
_id: "213123123123"
conversation:[
        {
            "messageInformation" : {
                "deliveryStatus" : "sent"

            },
            "userId" : 33
        },
        {
            "messageInformation" : {
                "deliveryStatus" : "sent",
                "userInfo" : [ ]
            }
        }
  ]}
]
```

I need the total count. I had try try **elemMatch** but it only return the first element

```
let counter = await ProjectConversation.find({
conversation: {
        $elemMatch: {
          userId :{$exists: true},
          "messageInformation.deliveryStatus": deliveryStatus.Sent
        }
      }
}, {
      _id: 0,
      conversation.$: 1
    });
```

It will be fine if I get the object and do the count by using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and use `$count` to count the number of documents that matches the `$match` property, eg :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$conversation"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "conversation.messageInformation.deliveryStatus": "sent",
            "conversation.userId": {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $count: "NumberOfMsgSent"
    }
])
```

On [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZlnO5hwn4r0)